# how to put constraint on .deleteOne

Tags: javascript

```
authorSchema.pre('deleteone', async function(next) {
    try {
        const query = this.getFilter();
        const hasBook = await Book.exists({
            author: query.id
        })
        if (hasBook) {
            next(new Error('This author still has books.'))
        } else {
            next()
        }
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
})
```

This code snippet belongs to author schema. I want to delete those author who doesn't has any book But this code delete those authors also who has books. Information of books will be taken from book schema.

Suggest some changes in my following code snippet.

Comment: Is it related to MongoDB?

Comment: Is this some kind of framework?

Comment: Hi Deepika, The code looks good but you have missing semicolons (;) issue. Try placing `;` after `})` , `next()` and other statment end. Test the code after placing the`;`.
I hope you understand what I am suggesting,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the comment above.

```
authorSchema.pre('deleteOne', async function(next) {
    try {
        const query = this.getFilter();
        const hasBooks = await Book.exists({
            author: query._id // This is a Change Instead of id try using _id
        });
        
        if (hasBooks) {
            next(new Error('This author still has books.'));
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: it doesn't work